# POSIX read(2), unexpected behavior

Tags: c, posix, undefined-behavior

I have some issues using read(2) in a learning test.

The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    size_t length;
    read(0, &length, sizeof(length));
    printf("input = %u\n", length);

    return 0;
}
```

I suppose that this code will read 8 bytes (i.e. ascii char) from stdio, storing them in the length variable. Then it will print to stdout the corresponding unsigned int value of the 8 bytes.

So, let my test be the following: running this program from a linux terminal, and just hit 'enter'. I'd expect that the value of length is just 10 (the ascii value of line feed char).

But running this test (many times too):

```
$ ./test
len = 4195338
```

But this version of the code works like I'd expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    size_t length;
    int b = 123;
    ssize_t n = read(0, &length, sizeof(length));
    printf("input = %u\n", length);

    return 0;
}


$ ./test
input = 10
```

So, what's the point? 
Why if I add some random and unused variables, and if I store the return value of the read(), the output from the same input will differ?

N.B. I know that read(2) is a raw system call and is not supposed to read input from terminal, this is just a learning question.

Comment: How is `./test` feeding data into your program?  What is being typed at the the program — what is it getting as the input data.  (And there's still a `len = 4195338` which should presumably be `input = 4195338`.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I simply run the program from terminal, and then hit enter from keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sizeof(size_t) == 8`, the code will read 8 bytes — true.

In general, those bytes will not all be ASCII (meaning some will have the 8th bit set and values in the range 0x80..0xFF which is not part of ASCII).

However, there is no conversion of characters.  If your file contains `12345678`, the value will be 0x3132333435363738 (or maybe 0x3837363534333231).  If you need conversion, you don't use `read(2)`.

The `printf()` format should be `%zu` (C99) or `%lu` (C89 with `size_t` equivalent to 64-bit `unsigned long`; it can't be `unsigned long long` and C89, of course).

Note that your sample output is not from your sample code.  The sample output says `len = ...` but the code would generate `input = ...`.  So, one of your problems may be that you are not testing what you think you are testing.

You comment:

> I know that read(2) is a raw system call and is not supposed to read input from terminal.

The `read(2)` system call is (probably) used by functions such as `getchar()` to read from the terminal.  It is not incorrect to use it to read from the terminal.  It probably is incorrect to read from the terminal into something other than a character array.

---

> I simply run the program from terminal, and then hit enter from keyboard.

Oh.  Bother.  It never occurred to me that you'd do that.

Well, you read one byte of data into a variable that needs 8 bytes and you get garbage.  Your variable was not reliably initialized.

Here's an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) with sample outputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t length = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    int nbytes = read(0, &length, sizeof(length));
    printf("nbytes = %d: input = %zu (0x%zX)\n", nbytes, length, length);
    return 0;
}
```

Two sample runs:

```
$ ./test

nbytes = 1: input = 18446744073709551370 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0A)
$ ./test
12345678
nbytes = 8: input = 4050765991979987505 (0x3837363534333231)
$ ./test < /dev/null
nbytes = 0: input = 18446744073709551615 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
$
```

Do you see what's happening there?  Note that the SSCCE code pays attention to and reports on the number of bytes read.  It is important to always check on the return value from read-like operations (and here, that means `read()` specifically); if you don't get as much data as you expected, your results are likely not what you expected either.  Using the value after the 'hit newline' case is probably 'undefined behaviour', though the behaviour shown is what you'd normally get.

(Testing with GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.3 — Intel chips, little-endian.)

Comment: Sorry, `len = ...` is just an error during copy-paste. I edited. Thank you for the other info.

Comment: There are major advantages to providing an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)), because then we can see what you're really doing.  It would only add 6-10 lines (max) to the code.  It might also answer the mystery of what the input to your program is — you've not shown that yet.

Comment: There are just the main()-related LOC. Btw I'll edit the question. ^^

Comment: Thank you very much. But, *why* in the 2nd version I got 10 as output? The length variable was not initialized, too.

Comment: Pure accident that your `length` variable happened to be initialized to 0, so reading a newline (`'\n'` or 10) happens to set the least significant byte to 10.  I got 0x0A in that byte.  You're using a little-endian (Intel) CPU too.  Since `length` is not explicitly initialized in your code, you cannot predict reliably what value you'll get when you modify one of the bytes because the other seven bytes don't have a determinate value.

Answer (score 1):

if size_t is 8 bytes try %llu in your printf